# INSERT query of execute() returns null... strange behaviour: Titanium(Android)

Tags: titanium

i created a database in sqlite manager and now want to insert some data into it. On executing the

```
var resultSet =dbConn.execute(query, valueArray);
```

resultSet returns null.

But when i execute `dbConn.getRowCount()` it confirms that row has been added.

Is iit possible that for execute('INSERT...') to complete successfully even after returning null !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup. It doesn't return a resultSet. If there's a SQL error, it'll be thrown.

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/TiDatabaseProxy.m#L174

Comment: but for SELECT query it does return resultSet. SO return value depends on the query being executed ?

Comment: Correct. SELECT returns. UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT do not.